# How to hide JFreeChart XYSeries yaxis?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is there a way to hide a JFreeChart XYSeries yaxis?
The yaxis is meaningless on logic analyzer display.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`setVisible()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#setVisible%28boolean%29), as shown below.

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
range.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

hide horizontal and vertical labels

> ValueAxis range = xyPlot.getRangeAxis();
>
> range.setVisible(false);
>
> ValueAxis domain = xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
>
> domain.setVisible(false);